# Realm.js - default.realm already opened on current thread with different schema

Tags: react-native, realm

Can somebody explain to me what this is and how can I solve it? Stuck on it for a day now. I've got my collaborator to pull my repo and I think he had it running while doing the pull. Getting that error since. I've deleted the app on every simulator the app was run on but no luck. I can run it without a problem on my end.

`/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79EC3F92-1B4C-44BC-B82C-66259AA1BA54/data/Containers/Data/Application/855B681D-A75D-4683-8470-05E74A19E142/Documents/default.realm' already opened on current thread with different schema`

This is how I open realm:

```
let realm = new Realm({
  schema: [
    HomeSchema,
    NewsSchema,
    DocumentSchema,
    NoticeboardSchema,
    VideosSchema,
    ImageSchema,
    EventsSchema,
    CourseSchema,
  ],
});

class MyScreen extends React.Component {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using v6.0.0 - v6.1.4, Realm instances weren't cached, and you might have observed this error message. In [v6.1.5](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#615-release-notes-2020-11-4) there is a fix so Realm instances are cached.

Comment: Yes thank you, all explained here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3435